# CSS/HTML Эмуляция металлического цвета

Tags: html, css, background

Заказчик изволил фон на странице "бело металлического глянцевого" цвета. Из диалога стало ясно что требуется структура как тело бота из игры Portal2. Я не представляю как это решить оптимально, без использования фонового изображения, на адаптивной верстке. Если кто сталкивался - прошу совета.

[image: фон]

Comment: как вам такие 2 варианта? [1 вариант](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/VeBoXx) и [2 вариант](https://codepen.io/natacoops/pen/xLxQVj)

Answer (score 1):

Вам в комментариях [Андрій Панчій](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/267845/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9-%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D1%96%D0%B9) указал такие варианты, я думаю этого будет вполне достаточно. Если нет – можно поиграть с градиентом и тенями.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #aaa;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  border: solid 0.625em transparent;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 6.25em;
  height: 6.25em;
  border-radius: 1.09375em;
  font: 2.5em/5em Satisfy, cursive;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px currentColor, 0 0 2px dimgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #eedc00, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: conic-gradient(#edc800, #e3b600, #f3cf00, #ffe800, #ffe900, #ffeb00, #ffe000, #ebc500, #e0b100, #f1cc00, #fcdc00, #ffe500, #fad900, #eec200, #e7b900, #f7d300, #ffe800, #ffe300, #f5d100, #e6b900, #e3b600, #f4d000, #ffe400, #ebc600, #e3b600, #f6d500, #ffe900, #ffe90a, #edc800) content-box, linear-gradient(#f6d600, #f6d600) padding-box, radial-gradient(rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9), rgba(120, 120, 120, 0) 70%) 50% bottom/80% 0.46875em no-repeat border-box;
}
button:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #c9c9c9, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: conic-gradient(#d7d7d7, #c3c3c3, #cccccc, #c6c6c6, #d3d3d3, #d8d8d8, #d5d5d5, #d8d8d8, #d3d3d3, #c5c5c5, #c0c0c0, #bfbfbf, #d0d0d0, #d9d9d9, #d1d1d1, #c5c5c5, #c8c8c8, #d7d7d7, #d5d5d5, #cdcdcd, #c4c4c4, #d9d9d9, #cecece, #c5c5c5, #c5c5c5, #cdcdcd, #d8d8d8, #d9d9d9, #d7d7d7) content-box, linear-gradient(#d4d4d4, #d4d4d4) padding-box, radial-gradient(rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9), rgba(120, 120, 120, 0) 70%) 50% bottom/80% 0.46875em no-repeat border-box;
}
button:nth-child(3) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #bc7e6b, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: conic-gradient(#d95641, #b14439, #b2453a, #d25645, #d56847, #d05441, #b85137, #b2453a, #c34f40, #df4647, #a94338, #c94943, #c85442, #a4413c, #d9543a, #d1564e, #ab4338, #bb4a3c, #dc5843, #b94839, #aa4237, #c24e42, #ce523f, #ab4338, #dd5944, #ca4d33, #ab4338, #cb503e, #d95641) content-box, linear-gradient(#ad3b36, #ad3b36) padding-box, radial-gradient(rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9), rgba(120, 120, 120, 0) 70%) 50% bottom/80% 0.46875em no-repeat border-box;
}
button:nth-child(4) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #c7aca0, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: conic-gradient(#e6c9bf, #d2b5aa, #cbaea3, #d4b5ab, #e5c3bd, #d9c0b4, #d9bcb1, #c5a399, #e3c6bc, #e7cac0, #dec0b5, #d3b6ab, #cfada1, #d4b6ac, #e2c6c0, #e2c6c0, #d2b1a6, #d2b1a6, #d1b4a9, #e1c4ba, #e5c9be, #dec1b6, #d3b6ab, #ceb0a6, #cfada3, #d2b5aa, #dabdb2, #e5c9be, #e6c9bf) content-box, linear-gradient(#e5c9be, #e5c9be) padding-box, radial-gradient(rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9), rgba(120, 120, 120, 0) 70%) 50% bottom/80% 0.46875em no-repeat border-box;
}
```

```html
<button>gold</button>
<button>silver</button>
<button>bronze</button>
<button>titanium</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из предоставленного Вами изображения в PS выбрать участок, который Вам больше подходит, размером 1x1px, сделать его фоном и размножить `background: url(../path/conpress-image.jpg)center repeatX;`

Comment: 1x1 здесь будет явно не достаточно, ибо на 1 пиксель поместится лишь один пиксель определенного цвета, что можно эффективней сделать через background-color.

Comment: @Vadizar а причем здесь background-color? background-color даст установленный Вами цвет, но не металический блеск, экспериментируйте с изображением, можно и 1x1 сделать, если руки прямые

Comment: На 1 пиксель поместится один цвет) Нет смысла добавлять такую картинку)

Comment: @Vadizar может я, конечно, не прав на счет 1px, но попробовать стоит, тут зависит от результата, какой Вы хотите получить чтобы соответствовал Вашим потребностям. Ну сделайте 100 на 100 px, хватит так? Других способов нет, но если найдете, дайте знать.